# I want to make certain rows delete automatically based on age

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I am creating a spreadsheet and would like to have rows drop off automatically at a certain age. Is there a way to do this?
My company submits engineering requests to our NY office, and I have created a job tracker to monitor the time from submittal to receipt of plans. My boss would like it if I can figure out how to make the data rows drop off after a certain time period. I've gotten all the formulas in for day counts and auto-updating with addition of new jobs, but I don't know how to go about this task.
Thank you for any input!

Answer (score 0):

Something like the code below should do the trick. In this example I am starting from row two and checking a date in column F to see if this is greater than the defined interval days old (21 here), you can change the initialisation of these variables as you require:

```
Sub delete_old()

    Dim rowDate
    Dim curDate
    Dim interval
    Dim curAdd
    Dim vCell As Range

    ' set interval to an appropriate no of days
    interval = 21 ' can be more precise e.g. for 5 mins: (1 / 24) / 12
    curDate = Now()

    ' assuming we want to start from row 2 and that date is in column F
    Set vCell = Range("F2")

    ' Set Do loop to stop when an empty cell is reached.
    Do Until IsEmpty(vCell)
        curAdd = vCell.Address
        If curDate - vCell.Value >= interval Then
            vCell.EntireRow.Delete
            Set vCell = Range(curAdd)
        Else
            Set vCell = Range(curAdd).Offset(1, 0) ' next row
        End If
    Loop

    Set vCell = Nothing

End Sub
```

You will need to call this automatically upon an event such as saving or opening the workbook. Let me know if you need assistance setting this up or any clarifications on the code above.